# Semantic Issue Use of undeclared identifier '_normalTexture'

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, xcode6

I am developing a aeroplane game (using gyro sensor) for iPhone using Xcode.
The planes can tilt depending on motion of phone. Right now i am stuck at this error

> Semantic Issue Use of undeclared identifier '_normalTexture'

The code in the file is as follows

```
#import "SKButton.h"
#import <objc/message.h>



@implementation SKButton

#pragma mark Texture Initializer

/**
 * Override the super-classes designated initializer, to get a properly set SKButton in every case
 */
- (id)initWithTexture:(SKTexture *)texture color:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size {
    return [self initWithTextureNormal:texture selected:nil disabled:nil];
}

- (id)initWithTextureNormal:(SKTexture *)normal selected:(SKTexture *)selected {
    return [self initWithTextureNormal:normal selected:selected disabled:nil];
}

/**
 * This is the designated Initializer
 */
- (id)initWithTextureNormal:(SKTexture *)normal selected:(SKTexture *)selected disabled:(SKTexture *)disabled {
    self = [super initWithTexture:normal color:[UIColor whiteColor] size:normal.size];
    if (self) {
        [self setNormalTexture:normal];
        [self setSelectedTexture:selected];
        [self setDisabledTexture:disabled];
        [self setIsEnabled:YES];
        [self setIsSelected:NO];

        _title = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
        [_title setVerticalAlignmentMode:SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter];
        [_title setHorizontalAlignmentMode:SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeCenter];

        [self addChild:_title];
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark Image Initializer

- (id)initWithImageNamedNormal:(NSString *)normal selected:(NSString *)selected {
    return [self initWithImageNamedNormal:normal selected:selected disabled:nil];
}

- (id)initWithImageNamedNormal:(NSString *)normal selected:(NSString *)selected disabled:(NSString *)disabled {
    SKTexture *textureNormal = nil;
    if (normal) {
        textureNormal = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:normal];
    }

    SKTexture *textureSelected = nil;
    if (selected) {
        textureSelected = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:selected];
    }

    SKTexture *textureDisabled = nil;
    if (disabled) {
        textureDisabled = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:disabled];
    }

    return [self initWithTextureNormal:textureNormal selected:textureSelected disabled:textureDisabled];
}




#pragma -
#pragma mark Setting Target-Action pairs

- (void)setTouchUpInsideTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
    _targetTouchUpInside = target;
    _actionTouchUpInside = action;
}

- (void)setTouchDownTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
    _targetTouchDown = target;
    _actionTouchDown = action;
}

- (void)setTouchUpTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
    _targetTouchUp = target;
    _actionTouchUp = action;
}

#pragma -
#pragma mark Setter overrides

- (void)setIsEnabled:(BOOL)isEnabled {
    _isEnabled = isEnabled;
    if ([self disabledTexture]) {
        if (!_isEnabled) {
            [self setTexture:_disabledTexture];
        } else {
            [self setTexture:_normalTexture];
        }
    }
}

- (void)setIsSelected:(BOOL)isSelected {
    _isSelected = isSelected;
    if ([self selectedTexture] && [self isEnabled]) {
        if (_isSelected) {
            [self setTexture:_selectedTexture];
        } else {
            [self setTexture:_normalTexture];
        }
    }
}

#pragma -
#pragma mark Touch Handling

/**
 * This method only occurs, if the touch was inside this node. Furthermore if
 * the Button is enabled, the texture should change to "selectedTexture".
 */
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self isEnabled]) {
        objc_msgSend(_targetTouchDown, _actionTouchDown);
        [self setIsSelected:YES];
    }
}

/**
 * If the Button is enabled: This method looks, where the touch was moved to.
 * If the touch moves outside of the button, the isSelected property is restored
 * to NO and the texture changes to "normalTexture".
 */
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self isEnabled]) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, touchPoint)) {
            [self setIsSelected:YES];
        } else {
            [self setIsSelected:NO];
        }
    }
}

/**
 * If the Button is enabled AND the touch ended in the buttons frame, the
 * selector of the target is run.
 */
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];

    if ([self isEnabled] && CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, touchPoint)) {
        objc_msgSend(_targetTouchUpInside, _actionTouchUpInside);
    }
    [self setIsSelected:NO];
    objc_msgSend(_targetTouchUp, _actionTouchUp);
}

@end
```

Comment: What is your class interface? Do you have normalTexture declared there as a property?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare normalTexture in your .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) SKTexture *normalTexture;
```

Xcode will then show a warning that this property will not be synthesised in order not to override the one from its superclass. To solve this problem, go back to your .m file and, right below `@implementation SKButton`, write:

```
@dynamic normalTexture;
```

Now, replace every use of `_normalTexture` with `normalTexture` and you should be good to go.